# iOS Framework upgraded to Swift 4.2 exported wastes too much space

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks

I've got a framework written in both Obj-c and Swift. I had to upgrade it to `Swift 4.2` to be compiled with `Xcode 10.3`. In release mode, if I try to export it with `Xcode 10.3`, it wastes **180MB** of space, instead of just **18 MB** with `Xcode 10.1`. Is it possible? I've only upgraded Swift code to be compilable.

Comment: Try set `Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries` to `false` in *Build Settings* of your framework

Comment: @Michcio that's correct! Now it doesn't include Swift libraries inside framework. Now I've got another problem. In a demo project, when I include my exported framework, it asks to enable `bitcode`. However I've got a dependency which hasn't got enabled bitcode. Any suggestion now?

Comment: Unfortunately - not. I had a similar problem and I need to disable `bitcode` in demo project also. I looked for another solution, but I didn't find anything.

Comment: The only solution was to update the embedded library, hoping that it lets you to enable bitcode. If not I think that there's not solution..